Sony Noise-Cancelling Headphones WH-1000XM4 pair but don't connect
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04LTS and I have a WH-1000XM4 Sony headphones set.
They pair correctly in the Bluetooth menu, where are shown, but I can't connect with them. They worked just fine before installing PulseAudio, unfortunately, after the installation(and removal) this strange behavior persists. What could I install/check?

I also had problem connecting, This answer worked for me.
